# How to handle building my own social media site side project while working at Google or Facebook?

Tags: conflict-of-interest

I am currently building a social media website that caters to casual gamers as a side project and have been offered a job at Facebook and Google.

Since Facebook and Google both have their own social media businesses, will me working on my social media website side project (during my own time and with my own resources) be a conflict of interest and reason for them to sue me in the future if my website generates some revenue?

Is there any way to handle this so that I can continue working on my project?

Comment: Seems like an easy question to ask whoever made you the offer, before you accept it.

Comment: turn down the offers... this is clear conflict of interest

Comment: Ask HR, your contract or letter of offer may have specifics on side projects, we cannot answer it here.

Comment: While this may or may not be something that you could negotiate with the companies themselves when you are being hired, as The Wandering Dev Manager says, the best resource is your company's HR, not this forum. Meanwhile, if you want to continue asking your question here, you may want to consider re-phrasing it to something like, "How do I negotiate being able to continue working on my side projects when it may present a conflict-of-interest with a job offer?" As long as this question hasn't been answered before already to your satisfaction :D.

Answer (score 3):

The right answer here is perhaps "just ask them", and their answer to that would most certainly be "no, you cannot do that" but I want to add some insights on why you would get that answer.

This sounds like a textbook example of conflict of interest. How would you ensure that your exposure to the social media business gained at work will not intentionally or subconsciously spill over into your personal project?

More importantly, how would you defend it in court, if you are asked to? The side with a deeper pocket usually has better chances of winning a lawsuit. Facebook and Google certainly have much deeper pockets than you. However, if your project becomes far more popular than theirs and generates your truckloads of revenue (and not "some" revenue, as you say), you may not have to worry about that.

I am just using the following example to explain the point: your project gives users the option to broadcast a live video to their group, with the user comments being prefixed with a timestamp. You came up with this idea either independently or in following up on a similar idea discussed at work, but try defending it as your own idea in court against Facebook attorneys.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there any way to handle this so that I can continue working on my
>   project?

Yes.

Before you accept an offer, disclose your plans and gain your employer's agreement in writing to allow you to continue working on your project. Then, check with your lawyer to ensure this agreement is sufficient to stand up against a conflict of interest lawsuit.

If your potential employer won't sign such an agreement, move on to the next potential employer.

That way, you'll be sure to be protected.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can.  You'd be directly competing with your employer and it would be reasonable to assume you have access to their code.  If you want to continue working at Google or Facebook, find another side project that doesn't compete with them, and clear it with them that it would be ok to work on it (they may have plans to enter a market they aren't yet in).  Or you can quit and work on this project, but you still have the possibility that you've seen their code, so you'd likely have to wait to even start for a few years.  Only a lawyer can help you here I would think.